# How do I send soap/php xml request with nested tags and secure header

Tags: xml, nested

I'm having a problem sending an xml request to a web service using soap and php.

I've spent a few days reading answers here and other sites but can't find examples that match what I want to do. I have to send a request that has nested xml tags and a secure header login.

Here's the request I need to make:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetAccommodationByCode>
         <tem:getAccommodationByCodeRequest>
            <tem:credentials>
               <tem:username>userhere</tem:username>
               <tem:password>passhere</tem:password>
            </tem:credentials>
            <tem:accommodationCode>prodcode</tem:accommodationCode>
            <tem:interval></tem:interval>
         </tem:getAccommodationByCodeRequest>
      </tem:GetAccommodationByCode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to make a php request using this xml.

Here's my attempt:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$wsdl = 'wsdl url here...';

$trace = true;
$exceptions = false;

$xml_array['username'] = 'pass123';
$xml_array['password'] = 'test123';
$xml_array['accommodationCode'] = '12345';

try
{

   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
   $response = $client->GetAccommodationByCode($xml_array);
}

catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo "Error!";
   echo $e -> getMessage ();
   echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}

var_dump($response);

?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Tom

Comment: Please do post you attempts, the problem might be as little as a wrong parameter order you overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a a WSDL to php generator to ensure the way to send the request.

You should try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.